# color of text in an li html tag on mouseover

Tags: css

Can i change the color of text in an "li" html tag on mouseover?

```html
<li style=" border:2px; border-color:white;">
  <a href="testrequestform.php" title=" Test Request">Test Request</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Use the ``:hover`` pseudo class in CSS.

Comment: explain please :hover  pseudo class and an example

Comment: @DeviSChandran What are you doing with accepting the answer? constantly accepting and removing it with every one..Plz dont play around here

Comment: @Tushar Gupta I am just a new user only member for 3 days to used this Stack Overflow community... Being a new user i cannot know how to accept an answer.. ..sorry for my fault.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this to your css

```
ul li a:hover, ul li a:focus {
 color:red;
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You should use `:hover` pseudo element. Like this sample.

`li a:hover` selects all `a` elements inside a `li` element on mouse over.

from this [short CSS Selectors reference|](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

> `:hover` Select and style an element when you mouse over it.

Code:

```css
li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li style=" border:2px; border-color:white;">
  <a href="testrequestform.php" title=" Test Request">Test Request</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this Helps:-

```
 li a:hover {
     color:red;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:hover` pseudo element.

```css
li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<li style=" border:2px; border-color:white;">
  <a href="testrequestform.php" title=" Test Request">Test Request</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the anchor tag, you can use this css code...

```
a:hover
{
   color: yourDesiredColor;
}
```